# Excel issues with positioning table after pasting in PPT

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

Revised...

I am able to copy and paste an embedded table from Excel to PPT, however I am having difficulty positioning the table. The code below pastes the table, but than generates a *"Run-time error of Selection.ShapeRange: Invalid Request."*

I have limited experience and have been spent the past few weeks trying to figure it out, but do not know where to go from here.

```
 'Copy Range from Excel
 Range("B4:E11").Copy

 'Paste Embeded File into Excel
     PPAPP.ActivePresentation.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting"
     PPAPP.ActivePresentation.Application.CommandBars.ReleaseFocus
    End With

'Position Table in Excel 
   With PPAPP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
      .Name = "SummaryTable"
      .Left = 1.08 * 72
       .Top = 1.9 * 72
      .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
      .Height = 5.11 * 72
      .Width = 11.8 * 72
        End With
```

Comment: a [mcve] will help us help you a lot better.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman does the revised question work?

Comment: instead of using `ActivePresentation` and `ActiveWindow` bind the **specific** powerpoint file to a variable and run the code of that. Also, avoid `Selection`. Tie a variable to that specific object (by name, say) and run the code against that.